# How can I get the navigation menu item in php?

Tags: php, html, navbar, menuitem

I am created a navigation bar with bootstrap. I want to get the navigation menu item name with PHP code. I was trying to do that with 'GET' method but I cannot do that without changing the page. Here I attached the nav-bar code.

```
<body>

    <!--  ======================== Navigation Bar ==============================  -->

    <section id="nav-bar">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light static-top">
            <div class="container-fluid p-0" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../images/logo.png"/></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <div class="hori-selector"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>

    <?php 

        echo "Selected Item"; // display selected navigation item here.

    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my index.php page body. I want to get the selected item name on the same index.php page. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want change page body without reload whole page, should use JavaScript or Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JavaScript and Ajax to solve this